# Draggable and hide

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

For a project I need a box, which often can find in Desktop application Editors. The box has three areas. One Content area, a tilebar and a sidebar.
If a person drag the tilebar, the sidebar grow up. The sidebar need a minimal widht. By a cklick on the tilebar the sidebar dissapear.
The contentarea use allways 100% of the available width...

I saw that in an other direction in the chatbar here [http://drop.io/hgjw8fb](http://drop.io/hgjw8fb#)
I draw that here:

[What i Want http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/6174/sodragandhidearea.gif](http://img411.imageshack.us/img411/6174/sodragandhidearea.gif)

Can anyone tell me how to make this with minimal markup or where I can find a plugin in Jquery for this? I use jquery and jqueryUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used and love the jQuery layout plugin found here: [Main page jQuery Layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/)

Here is a very simple demo from that site also [Demo - minimalist](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/example.html)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Splitter Plugin](http://www.methvin.com/splitter/) - Although you'll have to add the click to collapse/expand functionality yourself.